# I have a Jtextarea and certain parts of it are highlighted using a highlighter. I use Jtextarea.paint()

Tags: java, swing, printing, highlight, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea (textarea) that is populated with text.  Certain areas of the text have been highlighted with a highlighter.

```
Highlighter highlighter = textarea.getHighlighter();
HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.lightGray);
```

My problem is that when I print the JTextArea the highlighting does not print.

```
textarea.print(new MessageFormat("SearchTerm: "+
        SearchTerm.getText().toUpperCase()+"\n"),
        new MessageFormat("Page - {0}"),true,null,null,true);
```

Highlighted JTextArea

[image]

This is what prints:
Result of printing JTextArea:
[image]